# Subclipse - ckeckout directory to existing project

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, subclipse

Is it possible to ckeckout directory from SVN repo to existing project? My motivation: I using PyDev and have a directory with python package and I want to check it out. But problem is subpackages don't see root Python package and I can't add to PYTHONPATH directory which is *outside* the project.

What I need is to create a directory with a project and checkout directory with my python package *into* project directory. But I can't do it with Sublclipse, because it checkout python package directly to the project directory.

Comment: In Pydev you can add directories that are outside the project to the `PYTHONPATH`. Bring up the project properties and then select `PyDev - PYTHONPATH`. Now select the `External Libraries` tab. Use the `add source folder` button to specify where your external directory resides.

Comment: It looks like a hack but it works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You must not "check out" the directory, you have to "export" it. You can export anything from svn into any directory.

Also you could simply copy the other directory (from another check out) and delete the hidden `.svn` directory below it. If the directory contains subdirectories, every `.svn` directory must be deleted in the subdirectories as well.

Comment: No, export is not sufficient, because I need to develop my python code with all versioning features of SVN.